# View not taking the same height as parent RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve the layout on the right of the image below. What I am currently getting is on the left.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/garment_grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/gridview_image_placeholder"
        android:contentDescription="@string/blank"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/garment_grid_item_on_loan"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_borrowed"
        android:contentDescription="@string/blank"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/item_border"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`@drawable/item_border` (lime green is just to highlight the transparent areas):

[image: 9 patch drawable]

The `RelativeLayout` is used as an item template for a `GridView`. `garment_grid_item_image` is being populated in code. `garment_grid_item_on_loan` is the purple triangle in the top right whose visibility is controlled in code.

The `View` at the bottom uses a 9 patch and it is the one I'm having trouble with. I want it to be as tall as the parent `RelativeLayout` but neither `match_parent` or `fill_parent` work. What can I do to get it to work?

Comment: Could you not put `android:background="@drawable/item_border"` on to the `RelativeLayout` instead of using another `View` within? Or have I missed what you're doing here?

Comment: That would involve setting padding on it which would have to change for different screen sizes. I want to use 3 different 9 patch images (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried your layout with some similar images and it works fine when set as the root element in an Activity.

It could be to do with your RelativeLayout having wrap_content as its size, with the child Views not specifying a size to wrap. Try specifying a fixed size just to see if the problem goes away, then go from there.